# How to check space at the beginning of the string?

Tags: java

How can i check the white space at the beginning of the string.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "check"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

you can try `myString.startswith(" ")`

or `myString.matches("^ +.*")`

...and to remove bordering white spaces from each side: `myString.trim()`

Comment: If you want to check for any whitespace (not just a space character, but also tab, newline, etc), you can use `myString.matches("^\\s+.*")`.

Comment: @arnaud, This is only check for a space not a `white space`. trim() removes characters between `\0` and ` ` which includes some characters which are not white spaces and misses some characters which are white spaces.

Comment: @arnaud - I think you need to add ".*" to the end of the match regex; otherwise it will only match strings that are entirely space.

Answer (score 6):

To check the first character is whitepace:

```
Character.isWhitespace(myString.charAt(0))
```

Or use a regex:

```
myString.matches("^\\s+.*")
```

**Edit:** Don't forget to check for null or zero-length strings first:

```
if (myString != null && myString.length() > 0) {
  ....  
}
```

Comment: What happens if `String myString = "";` is the line before yours?

Comment: @Bohemium: I was assuming sanity checks like null or zero length; I'm crediting the OP with enough savvy to check for these. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str=" hi";
    if(str.startsWith(""))
    {
        System.out.println("Space available");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO Space available");
    }
```

You can achieve it through different ways also. various way available to achieve this.

Comment: The question was: *white space*, not *space* (`' '`). There's a difference. *White space* is a class of characters, including `\n` for example.

Comment: Also the shown code does not even check for a space. Which string does not start with ""?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more...

```
public static boolean isStartingWithWhitespace(String str) {
   if (str == null || str.isEmpty())
      return false;

   return str.substring(0,1).trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Explanation: `trim` will remove leading and trailing white spaces. If the string exists and is not empty, then we create a new string from the first char and trim it. Now, if the result is empty, the the original string *did* start with a white space and we return true. Otherwise, the answer is "false".

*Note* - this solution can't compete with [Richard H's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572240/how-to-check-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-string/6572297#6572297), which is more elegant ;)

Answer (score -1):

it is simple just see
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

trim() method trim space at starting and ending of a string by check unicode value '\u0020' (value of space)(most minimum value in unicode is '\u0020' = space)
so it check every index from starting until get value greater than space unicode and also check from last until it get value greater than space and trim start & end. finally return substring without space at start and end.

Comment: String str="     hi   ji      ";
   str = str.trim();    
        System.out.println(str);