# Coding a program that essentially copies a file of code to an array and have the indentation saved into the array to be written out to seperate file

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting

```
private static StringTokenizer readFile(String inputFilename) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File(inputFilename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String fileContents = scanner.useDelimiter(";"+" "+"\\{"+"\\}"+"\\["+"\\]"+"\\("+"\\\\").next();

        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(fileContents,";"+" "+"\\{"+"\\}"+"\\["+"\\]"+"\\("+"\\\\");
        // \\W is an escape code, meaning all non regular letters/numbers

        return st1;
    }
```

This is how far I have gotten. Simply do not know how to manipulate the delimeter in a way that allows me to save the indentation or spacing info.

Any links to previous Syntax Highlighters in Java or even Python (but mostly Java) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your viewing.

Cheers,
ThtKoder

Edit: Sample Input (without all the fancy highlighting around keywords/variable names, etc.) and Output File:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // value a, b, and c
    double a = 2.3, b = 4, c = 5.6;
    double root1, root2;

    // calculate the determinant (b2 - 4ac)
    double determinant = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    // check if determinant is greater than 0
    if (determinant > 0) {

      // two real and distinct roots
      root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(determinant)) / (2 * a);
      root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(determinant)) / (2 * a);

      System.out.format("root1 = %.2f and root2 = %.2f", root1, root2);
    }

    // check if determinant is equal to 0
    else if (determinant == 0) {

      // two real and equal roots
      // determinant is equal to 0
      // so -b + 0 == -b
      root1 = root2 = -b / (2 * a);
      System.out.format("root1 = root2 = %.2f;", root1);
    }

    // if determinant is less than zero
    else {

      // roots are complex number and distinct
      double real = -b / (2 * a);
      double imaginary = Math.sqrt(-determinant) / (2 * a);
      System.out.format("root1 = %.2f+%.2fi", real, imaginary);
      System.out.format("\nroot2 = %.2f-%.2fi", real, imaginary);
    }
  }
}
```

Also as clarification, I meant to note that I mostly need help with saving indentation information, so that the stringtokenizer or other way of storing the file in RAM would also be able to write into a file.

Comment: please don't write new code using StringTokenizer. StringTokenizer has been a legacy class for a decade. To quote the StringTokenizer documentation: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post an example. Please note that indentation and syntax highlighting are connected but quite different. Your goal is generally unclear

Comment: Got it, thanks! Took a look at .split() as well, but could not seem to wrap my head around it either. However, I will take another look at java.util.regex package now.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add an example input and the required output.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to read a file but not save every byte/character but just the indentation?

If that is correct you could read the file line by line, and for each line just store the whitespace in the beginning of the line. Or even more compressed, just store a number how many whitespace characters you found.

What can help in these cases:

- [How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6572297/4222206